# How to get an encrypted file into a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

We are working on moving a .pgp encrypted file to a Data Extension. 
It's landing in a folder in the sFTP site, and I'm able to decrypt it, but I'm unable to get it into a Data Extension.

Salesforce gave me the following instructions, but I think there's a problem with the file name, as I'm getting errors that the file couldn't be found

1. File Transfer Decrypt the file.
2. File transfer the decrypted file into the FTP
3. Import the file from the FTP.

We're starting with a file that's 
Filenamehere.TXT.pgp

What would the file name for step number 2? 
Filenamehere.TXT ?

So far I've tried:
Filenamehere.TXT
Filenamehere.csv
Filenamehere.TXT.pgp
Filenamehere.TXT.csv

I'm running out of ideas. Anyone encountered this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

File Transfer and Decrypt the file from the FTP server to the Safehouse

Import the file from the Safehouse location.

The file name for the import should be the .CSV file as once extracted and decrypted it should be a CSV.

Once decrypted, the file will only be in the Safehouse, so you should do the import from there.