# Automation Questions

Tags: community, automationstudio, automation

I have a couple very simple questions relating to automation studio. These are very rudimentary questions, but need a little bit of guidance on certain concepts. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- If you were tasked with uploading an encrypted file into Salesforce, would the first activity be "file transfer" to decrypt the file and then use an "import activity" to move it into the desired DE? Or would you first use "import activity" and then use "file transfer" to decrypt? And if the file was not encrypted, would you start with import file activity?
- If you needed to combine the data of three separate DE's, would you use an "SQL query activity" in automation studio, or what would be another viable method? I've learned that you can relate or link DE's using attribute groups, I never was taught or shown examples though.

Answer (score 1):

Good questions:

1. If you were tasked with uploading an encrypted file into Salesforce,
   would the first activity be "file transfer" to decrypt the file and
   then use an "import activity" to move it into the desired DE? Or
   would you first use "import activity" and then use "file transfer"
   to decrypt? And if the file was not encrypted, would you start with
   import file activity?

   > See this link for a good answer
   > [How to get an encrypted file into a data extension?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235185/how-to-get-an-encrypted-file-into-a-data-extension)
2. If you needed to combine the data of three separate DE's, would you
   use an "SQL query activity" in automation studio, or what would be
   another viable method? I've learned that you can relate or link DE's
   using attribute groups, I never was taught or shown examples though.

   > Yes an SQL query activity is your best bet. Obviously, to combine data into one DE you common fields across all DEs (See SQL example below). In the context of your questions, Linking DEs would be the "Data Relationships" section of Email Studio (Subscribers). But this will not combine data from DEs. Data Relationships will allow you to join DEs together for you to leverage data filters in a complex way to and avoid needing to use SQL. Attribute Groups are actually a different thing (you still like DEs to one another). Attribute Groups are used to create the BU's data model in Contact Builder Data Designer. They are mainly used in Journeys for contact data purposes.

SQL Eg:

SELECT
Subscriberkey,
EmailAddress,
MobilePhone,
Firstname
FROM DE_1
UNION
SELECT
Subscriberkey,
EmailAddress,
MobilePhone,
Firstname
FROM DE_2
UNION
SELECT
Subscriberkey,
EmailAddress,
MobilePhone,
Firstname
FROM DE_3

Other stuff:
Watch this Youtube playlist for Automation Studio insight:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLntZFZH56rSfbiSZAp_8sgoxGDo3vD20A

Check out more of the SFMCTrailblazers youtube channel for more learning about SFMC.

Hope this helps mate,
Take care

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful @weenus23

Comment: Glad I could help man 
let me know if you want more resources when it comes to SFMC learning as well.